# C# LoadControl() (.ascx) and add into "this" rather than sub control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I'm good with Loading the control, using the `LoadControl("~/vitrualPath")`, so I have:

```
UserControl ctrl = (UserControl)LoadControl("~/controls/someControl.ascx");
this.Controls.Add(ctrl);
//plcCtrl.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

The trouble is that I wish to then loop through all the controls in the usercontrol:

```
foreach (Label c in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
  // It's a label for an input
  if (c.ID.Substring(0, 8) == "lblInput")
   {
     // Do some stuff with the control here
   }
}
```

However, the added controls aren't part of `this`, but part of `ctrl`

Is there a way I can add the contents of the loaded control to `this` or a way to loop through both `this` and `ctrl` in one hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to loop through both top-level labels and labels in `ctrl`, try `this.Controls.Concat(ctrl.Controls).OfType<Label>()` in your `foreach` loop.

You can also move your `if` into a LINQ `Where` call:

`.Where(l => l.ID.Substring(0, 8) == "lblInput")`

Comment: I'm liking the look of concatinating the two... That way no recusive loops and such like!

Comment: If you ever want to get all the labels in several levels of nested controls, say, recursion is the way to go. If you will only _ever_ care about the top level and this control, this is a simple solution.

Comment: Yes, I'm only interested in the top levels of each at the moment... However I'm also looking to pass values back to the controls, which means I'll still need the right target to go back to so may need to go the recursive route anyway.

Comment: You can access a given `Label`'s container via the `Parent` property, if this is what you're after.

Comment: Agreed, however it's making sure that's tracked - i.e. when I should use `this` or the `parent` to get back to the control. I'll get there,  but would like to not get too complex to maintain!

Answer (score 1):

By using a recursive function you don't need to worry about controls within sub levels/ containers. Something like this should be OK (all you need to do is to pass the top level control along with the id substring that you are interested in). So if the conditions are met it will do whatever you have intended to do with the control and at any sub level.

```
public void ProcessControl(Control control, string ctrlName)
{
    foreach (Label c in control.Controls.OfType<Label>())
   {
       // It's a label for an input
       if (c.ID.Substring(0, 8) == ctrlName)
       {
            // Do some stuff with the control here
       }
    }

    foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
    {
        ProcessControl(ctrl, ctrlName);        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write a recursive method that starts looping the controls in this.Controls and goes down the tree of controls. It will then also go in your user control and find your labels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to loop through both like you want.

You can easily create a method that receives a Control as parameter and iterate though its controls. Something like this:

```
void Function(Control control)
{
    foreach (Label c in control.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    {
       // It's a label for an input
       if (c.ID.Substring(0, 8) == "lblInput")
       {
         // Do some stuff with the control here
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the controls inside the user control by accessing the `this.Controls[index].Controls` I think, however it kind of depends what you are trying to achieve? Their might be a cleaner way of doing what you are trying to do?